# How to extract and stream .tar.xz directly to s3 bucket without saving locally

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a very large (~300GB) .tar.gz file.  Upon extracting it (with tar -xzvf file.tar.gz), it yields many .json.xz files. I wish to extract and upload the raw json files to s3 without saving locally (as I don't have space to do this).  I understand I could spin up an ec2 instance with enough space to extract and upload the files, but I am wondering how (or if) it may be done directly.

I have tried various versions of tar -xzvf file.tar.gz | aws s3 cp  - s3://the-bucket, but this is still extracting locally; also, it seems to be resulting in json.xz files, and not raw json.  I've tried to adapt this response from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868157/using-gzip-to-compress-files-to-transfer-with-aws-command) which zips and uploads a file, but haven't had any success yet.

I'm working on Ubuntu16.04 and quite new to linux, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is how I would do it. There may be more elegant/efficient solutions:

```
tar --list -zf file.tar.gz | while read -r item
do
    tar -xzvfO file.tar.gz $item | aws s3 cp - s3://the-bucket/$item
done
```

So you're iterating over the files in the archive, extracting them one-by-one to stdout and uploading them directly to S3 without first going to disk.

This assumes there is nothing funny going on with the names of the items in your `tar` file (no spaces, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this.  The only change I needed is that the -f flag needs to come last; this ended up not working for me, but it seems to be a problem with uploading large files to s3 and not with your solution.